# Regex tokenize issue

Tags: c#, regex, tokenize

I have strings input by the user and want to tokenize them. For that, I want to use regex and now have a problem with a special case.
An example string is

`Test + "Hello" + "Good\"more" + "Escape\"This\"Test"`
or the C# equivalent

`@"Test + ""Hello"" + ""Good\""more"" + ""Escape\""This\""Test"""`

I am able to match the `Test` and `+` tokens, but not the ones contained by the ". I use the " to let the user specify that this is literally a string and not a special token. Now if the user wants to use the " character in the string, I thought of allowing him to escape it with a \.

So the rule would be: Give me everything between two " ", but the character in front of the last " can not be a \.

The results I expect are: `"Hello"` `"Good\"more"` `"Escape\"This\"Test"`
I need the " " characters to be in the final match so I know that this is a string.

I currently have the regex `@"""([\w]*)(?<!\\"")"""` which gives me the following results: `"Hello"` `"more"` `"Test"`

So the look behind isn't working as I want it to be. Does anyone know the correct way to get the string like I want?

Comment: There is the next level: the \ normally can be escaped with another \\... So `\\"` vs `\"`

Comment: Xanatos is right, otherwise, [`"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%22%5b%5e%22%5c%5c%5d*(%3f%3a%5c%5c.%5b%5e%22%5c%5c%5d*)*%22&i=Test+%2b+%22Hello%22+%2b+%22Good%5c%22more%22+%2b+%22%5c%5c%5c%22Escape%5c%22This%5c%22Test%22&o=ixncsm) should work for you (C# [`var rx = "\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\""`](http://ideone.com/dTq91U)).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an adaption of a regex I use to parse command lines:

```
(?!\+)((?:"(?:\\"|[^"])*"?|\S)+)
```

Example [here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yE2vW7/1)

(adaption is the negative look-ahead to ignore `+` and checking for `\"` instead of `""`)

Hope this helps you.

Regards.

Edit:

If you aren't interested in surrounding quotes:

```
(?!\+)(?:"((?:\\"|[^"])*)"?|(\S+))
```

Comment: This will even match [`Test + \"Hello" + \"Good\"more" + \"Escape\"This\"Test"`](https://regex101.com/r/yE2vW7/2).

Answer (score 1):

To make it safer, I'd suggest getting all the substrings within unescaped pairs of `"..."` with the following regex:

```
^(?:[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"))+
```

It matches

- `^` - start of string (so that we could check each `"` and escape sequence)
- `(?:`  - Non-capturing group 1 serving as a container for the subsequent subpatterns

  - `[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*` - matches 0+ characters other than `"` and `\` followed with 0+ sequences of `\\.` (any escape sequence) followed with 0+ characters other than `"` and `\` (thus, we avoid matching the first `"` that is escaped, and it can be preceded with any number of escape sequences)
  - `("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*")` - Capture group 1  matching `"..."` substrings that may contain any escape sequences inside
- `)+` - end of the first non-capturing group that is repeated 1 or more times

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%3F%3A%5B%5E%22%5C%5C%5D*(%3F%3A%5C%5C.%5B%5E%22%5C%5C%5D*)*(%22%5B%5E%22%5C%5C%5D*(%3F%3A%5C%5C.%5B%5E%22%5C%5C%5D*)*%22))%2B&i=Test%20%2B%20%22Hello%22%20%2B%20%22Good%5C%22more%22%20%2B%20%5C%22Escape%5C%22This%5C%22Test%5C%22%20%2B%20%22f%22) and here is a [C# demo](http://ideone.com/mq0dlX):

```
var rx = "^(?:[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*(\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\"))+";
var s = @"Test + ""Hello"" + ""Good\""more"" + \""Escape\""This\""Test\"" + ""f""";
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, rx)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .SelectMany(m => m.Groups[1].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(p => p.Value).ToArray())
        .ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", matches));
```

**UPDATE**

If you need to remove the tokens, just match and capture all outside of them with this code:

```
var keep = "[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*";
var rx = string.Format("^(?:(?<keep>{0})\"{0}\")+(?<keep>{0})$", keep);
var s = @"Test + ""Hello"" + ""Good\""more"" + \""Escape\""This\""Test\"" + ""f""";
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, rx)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .SelectMany(m => m.Groups["keep"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(p => p.Value).ToArray())
        .ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", matches));
```

See [another demo](http://ideone.com/oigB3J)

Output: `Test +  +  + \"Escape\"This\"Test\" +`  for `@"Test + ""Hello"" + ""Good\""more"" + \""Escape\""This\""Test\"" + ""f""";`.

Comment: That looks very good. However, for the tokenization I want to replace the matches in my input string with empty strings because I have multiple expressions for different purposes. Your regex gives me as a match the whole string, so what would be the safest way to remove the matches? I could replace the first occurence of each of the strings found by the regex, but I am wondering if this a safe approach.

Comment: Ok, so you need to remove the `"Hello"`, `"Good\"more"`, and `"f"`, right? Let  me check...