# Parsing mathematical expressions in C#

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

As a project, I want to write a parser for mathematical expressions in C#. I know there are libraries for this, but want to create my own to learn about this topic.

As an example, I have the expression

```
min(3,4) + 2 - abs(-4.6)
```

I then create token from this string by specifying regular expressions and going through the expression from the user trying to match one of the regex. This is done from the front to the back:

```
    private static List<string> Tokenize(string expression)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        List<string> tokens = new List<string>();

        tokens.Add("^\\(");// matches opening bracket
        tokens.Add("^([\\d.\\d]+)"); // matches floating point numbers
        tokens.Add("^[&|<=>!]+"); // matches operators and other special characters
        tokens.Add("^[\\w]+"); // matches words and integers
        tokens.Add("^[,]"); // matches ,
        tokens.Add("^[\\)]"); // matches closing bracket

        while (0 != expression.Length)
        {
            bool foundMatch = false;

            foreach (string token in tokens)
            {
                Match match = Regex.Match(expression, token);
                if (false == match.Success)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                result.Add(match.Value);
                expression = Regex.Replace(expression, token, "");
                foundMatch = true;

                break;
            }

            if (false == foundMatch)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

This works quite well. Now I want the user to be able to enter strings into the expression. I found a question to this at [Regex tokenize issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35790482/regex-tokenize-issue) however the answer provide regex which match the text anywhere in the expression. However I need this to match only the first occurrence at the front of the expression so I can keep the order of token.
As an example see this:

`5 + " is smaller than " + 10`

should give me the tokens
`5` `+` `" is greater than "` `+` `10`

If possible I would also like to be able to enter escape characters so the user is able to use the character " in strings, like `"This is an apostrophe \" "` gives me the token `"This is an apostrophe " "`

The answer from Wiktor Stribiżew at that question looked really good, but I couldn't modify it so it only matches at the beginning and only one word. Help is appreciated!

Comment: What did you try? Not event `"(.*?)"` ? (Congrats Wiktor on being a reference now ;) )

Comment: Would recommend something like [Sprache](https://github.com/sprache/Sprache) or [Nitra](https://github.com/JetBrains/Nitra). Parsing complex expressions with regular expressions is a mugs game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny you referencing that question. I actually adopted (yet again) *my* answer in there to work for you here ;)

[Here's a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xI3pQd) showing the solution.

The regex is

```
(?!\+)(?:"((?:\\"|[^"])*)"?)
```

I changed the code to use capture groups to be able to in a simple manner **not** add the surrounding quotes. Also the loop removes the `+` sign separating the *tokens*.

Regards

Comment: Thank you! Now I can continue :)